# handling the "#" symbol in filenames

Tags: .htaccess, special-characters, filenames, symbols

Songs that contain a "#" in the track title give me a 404 error while trying to download from my site. How to fix this?

This is my current `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteRule ^download/([^/]*)-([^/]*).mp3$ download.php?download=$2&pl=$1
```

Answer (score 3):

The # is never reaching apache. It is a jump-marker and everything in the url after # is not sent to the webserver. The javascript:document.location.hash is jumping to an anchor in the page. You can escape the # with %23 which then should reach your webserver even without htaccess. As you use php, you can use htmlentities($filename) or urlencode($filename) to fix it during output.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can I achieve this? do I have to add something on my download.php file? preg_replace perhaps?

Comment: Example <a href="<?= urlencode( $filename ) ?>">title</a> . or a simple <a href="<?= str_replace("#","%23", $filename ) ?>">title</a> if its the only character causing problems. In your case you probably want to keep the "/" in the filename and not replace it to %2E which happens with urlencode.

Comment: It didn't work for me. i tried to put this on download.php. but it also uses another file called load.php which has this code :                                                     function safetitle($title){
    $title = strip_tags($title);
    $title = urlencode($title);
 $title = str_replace("+", " ", $title);
 return $title;                                 Not sure how to implement this. might need to hire someone to do it for me...

Comment: if you already have ... $title = urlencode( $title ) ... then it should work already. you could also go the opposite way and remove all special characters from your title like: ... $title = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/", "_", $title ) ... which will replace all special chars with _ . so it easily matches your ...[^/] ... seems your other titles work, only special chars are the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the
[Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html)

> By default the special characters such as `?`, `#`will be converted to their hexcode.Using the `[NE]` flag prevents that from happening.

```
 RewriteRule ^download/([^/]*)-([^/]*)\.mp3$ download.php?download=$2&pl=$1 [NE,QSA,NC,L]
```

The above example will redirect `/download-foo-bar.mp3`
 to `download.php?download=bar&pl=bar#1` . Omitting the `[NE]` flag will result in the `#`
being converted to its hexcode `%23`., which will then result in 404 not found error condition.

And in `RewriteRule` pattern ,dot (.) is a special characters, it matches any characters. Escape it using a backslash if you want to match a literal dot(.).

Comment: Strage, I still get 404 error nor found. after replacing with config with yours ( RewriteRule ^download/([^/]*)-([^/]*)\.mp3$ download.php?download=$2&pl=$1 [NE,QSA,NC,L])  Any advice?

Comment: @Rayan what is the url you are entering in your browser?